# VHDL 1-bit ALU - behavioral

Tags: vhdl

I just wrote this code of a 1-bit ALU with behavioral way.The code contains an overflow check. Can someone explain me if the code is correct ?
Here is the code:

```
entity ALU_VHDL is
port
(
  a, b: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  Operation : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);

  Carry_Out : out std_logic;
  Flag : out std_logic;
  Result : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
  );
 end entity ALU_VHDL;

 architecture Behavioral of ALU_VHDL is

signal Temp: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);

begin

process(a, b, Operation, temp) is
begin
  Flag <= '0';
  case Operation is
 when "000" => -- resu = a + b, flag = carry = overflow
    Temp   <= std_logic_vector((unsigned("0" & a) + unsigned(b)));
        Result <= temp(1 downto 0);
    Carry_Out   <= temp(2);
 when "001" => -- resu = |a - b|, flag = 1 iff a > b
    if (a >= b) then
       Result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) - unsigned(b));
       Flag   <= '0';
        else
       Result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) - unsigned(b));
       Flag   <= '1';
        end if;
 when "010" =>
    Result <= a and b;
 when "011" =>
    Result <= a or b;
 when "100" =>
    Result <= a xor b;
 when "101" =>
    Result <= not a;
 when "110" =>
        Result <= not b;
 when others => -- resu = a + not b + 1, flag = 0
    Temp   <= std_logic_vector((unsigned("0" & Nibble1) + unsigned(not Nibble2)) + 1);
    Result <= temp(1 downto 0);
    Flag   <= temp(2);
  end case;
end process;

end architecture Behavioral;
```

I am new in VHDL so any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way the entire semiconductor industry checks their code is to create a testbench and to simulate it. So, you need to do the same. You need a level of hierarchy above your ALU, into which you instantiate your ALU. You will then need some method of creating inputs and preferably some method of automatically checking the outputs.

Comment: Your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), missing the context clause invoking `library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; use.ieee.numeric_std.all;` and declarations for nibble1 and nibble2. Without a method of applying stimuli to a 'corrected' design model the functionality cannot be verified or critiqued. You appear to be using three ALUs.